# Is it possible to add a keyboard layout and dictionary to Swype?

Tags: swype, motorola-defy

I used the official Motorola upgrade tool and updated my Motorola Defy to Froyo (French firmware). Before the update, when I held the Q key on the Swype keyboard, many languages options were offered, and among them there was the Polish language. Now I don't have that option anymore, as there are far fewer languages available.

Is there any way to have that language installed back? I have tried Manylocale2, but it does NOT what I need: it changes the locale, but it will not add any languages to the language menu...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Swype Help](http://www.swypeinc.com/help.html)

> Swype supports text entry in a number
>   of languages. To switch between
>   languages:
>
> ```
> Tap the SYM key.
> Tap the key showing the abbreviation code for the currently
> ```
>
> active language (e.g. "EN" for
>   English).
>       A Language Choice window displays, showing available languages.
>       Select the desired language by tapping it in the list.
>
> To toggle between the current language
>   and last-used language, Swype from the
>   Swype key to the key with the current
>   Language indicator.

However if the Swype was preinstalled (as seems the case by way of the update given to you) it seems that you are stuffed as there is no way to add a language, or if it comes to that, edit a preinstalled language with Swype.

This is probably the one downside of Swype, whereby they have a business model to sell to carriers not to the public and a preinstalled Swype is neither updateable or removeable.

Solution: spend a couple of bucks on the excellent SwiftKey in the Market, it has editable and readily available language dictionaries and is very full featured and is directly comparable to Swype.

Comment: That's a pity because I just started to be proficient with Swype and this would force me to learn it all over again. But I will try :) Thanks!