# Changing Swype keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, swype

Is there anyway to change Swype from QWERTY to something else, like AZERTY?

Comment: You might wish to check [Is it possible to add a keyboard layout and dictionary to Swype?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/9726/16575)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried downloading a new language?

Go to Swype's settings in `Language and input` (or keyboard settings). Then, go to `Languages > Download languages`. You should see `Francais (AZERTY)`.